# App Engine - How to save a Blob?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, blob, blobstore

So I have an image saved as Blob. I look it up and crop it with the help of the `ImagesService`. But how can I save my newly generated `com.google.appengine.api.images.Image` as a Blob again? I found some examples using `com.google.appengine.api.files.FileService`, but the interface is deprecated.

```
ImagesService imagesService = ImagesServiceFactory.getImagesService();

Image oldImage = ImagesServiceFactory.makeImageFromBlob(new BlobKey(myBlobKey));

Transform crop = ImagesServiceFactory.makeCrop(0, 0, 0.5, 0.5);

Image newImage = imagesService.applyTransform(crop, oldImage);
```

What is the best (not deprecated) way to store it now?

Answer (score 2):

The current recommended method is to use the [Google Cloud Storage Client Library](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/googlecloudstorageclient/), which is an interface to [Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/products/cloud-storage/). There's a [5GB free quota](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas#Default_Gcs_Bucket) when using the default bucket.

It works similar to the Files API, by creating and writing files, but the system is more robust so there's some added complexity (albeit small once past the initial configuration).

I recommend you to take the steps outlined in the [What to do next](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/googlecloudstorageclient/#Java_What_to_do_next) section, and reading the [Getting Started](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/googlecloudstorageclient/getstarted) guide, which will tell you everything you need to now on how to implement it.